# mongodb return person if comments

Tags: mongodb

I have a query to return posts and person content types.

```
var query = {
  type: {
    $in: ["post", "person"]
  },
}
```

But I only want to return person if person has any comments, but posts always.

```
var query = {
  type: {
    $in: ["post", "person"]
  },
  // somehow make this only for person
  // comments: {"$exists": true}
}
```

Is this possible or should I use map reduce?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = {
    $or: [
        { type: "post" },
        { type: "person", comments: { $exists: true }},
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, I've just tested it:

```
db.things.find({$or: [ { type: "post" }, 
                      { type: "person", comments: { $exists: true }} ]})
```

I've initially thought that it is not possible to use same field name in query twice, but it was just an issue with some drivers. [here](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-dev/browse_thread/thread/54273045df481646) you can find discussion about this.

Also map/reduce usual not acceptable for real time queries, because it pretty slow.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about map/reduce and realtime queries.